# Why does clearing date input using Angular give different results?

Tags: html, angular, date, data-binding

I have a Component in my Angular project that shows a graph up to a particular date as picked by the user. The value in the date input must be a valid date. So when clicking the x button on the date picker, it should go to the current date and not be blank.

This is the html:

```
<input class="form-control input-sm" type="date" name="endDate" 
        [ngModel]="endDate | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'" (ngModelChange)="setEndDate($event);">
```

and the following code in the Component TS file:

```
endDate = new Date();

setEndDate(newValue) {

  if(newValue) {
    this.endDate = newValue;
    return;
  }

  this.endDate = new Date();
}
```

What I can't get my head around is that sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't. Specifically, when the date in the picker *is not* the current date, clicking the x results in it becoming the current date as intended. When the date in the picker *is* the current date, it goes blank and shows `mm/dd/yyyy`. It should just stay on the current date.

From testing it looks like the value is being set, but the picker does not update for some reason. I've tried changing the binding but this only resulted in it breaking completely. Any light that can be shed on why this works sometimes but not other times would be appreciated.

stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-oep55t

Comment: Can you provide a stackblitz or something similar ?

Comment: @Yvan  Added now in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use a viewChild for set the value of the nativeElement. Looks like endDate was never pass throught the input date after clear the value. I used the datePipe in the ts file in order to get the date formatted. Don't forget to add the datepipe into the providers in your module.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-268qje

Let me know if it's ok for you.

Comment: That does seem to work as intended. Could you elaborate on your answer as to why my solution did not work? This was the main point of my question

Comment: What i saw during my test was the input data ignore the value setted by the ngModel just after clicking on the 'x', I have no idea what happen, I google it and I didn't find anything regarding your issue. sorry about that.

Comment: But I am interested if you find any explanation